# Stretching an ellipse in an image to form a circle

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I want to stretch an elliptical object in an image until it forms a circle. My program currently inputs an image with an elliptical object (eg. coin at an angle), thresholds and binarizes it, isolates the region of interest using edge-detect/bwboundaries(), and performs regionprops() to calculate major/minor axis lengths.

Essentially, I want to use the 'MajorAxisLength' as the diameter and stretch the object on the minor axis to form a circle. Any suggestions on how I should approach this would be greatly appreciated. I have appended some code for your perusal (unfortunately I don't have enough reputation to upload an image, the binarized image looks like a white ellipse on a black background).

**EDIT**: I'd also like to apply this technique to the **gray-scale version of the image**, to examine what the stretch looks like.

code snippet:

```
rgbImage = imread(fullFileName);
redChannel = rgbImage(:, :, 1);
binaryImage = redChannel < 90;
labeledImage = bwlabel(binaryImage);
area_measurements = regionprops(labeledImage,'Area');
allAreas = [area_measurements.Area];
biggestBlobIndex = find(allAreas == max(allAreas));
keeperBlobsImage = ismember(labeledImage, biggestBlobIndex);
measurements = regionprops(keeperBlobsImage,'Area','MajorAxisLength','MinorAxisLength')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to figure out the transform required thanks to a lot of help on the matlab forums. I thought I'd post it here, in case anyone else needed it.

```
    stats = regionprops(keeperBlobsImage, 'MajorAxisLength','MinorAxisLength','Centroid','Orientation');
    alpha = pi/180 * stats(1).Orientation;
    Q = [cos(alpha), -sin(alpha); sin(alpha), cos(alpha)];
    x0 = stats(1).Centroid.';
    a = stats(1).MajorAxisLength;
    b = stats(1).MinorAxisLength;
    S = diag([1, a/b]);
    C = Q*S*Q';
    d = (eye(2) - C)*x0;
    tform = maketform('affine', [C d; 0 0 1]');
    Im2 = imtransform(redChannel, tform);
    subplot(2, 3, 5); 
    imshow(Im2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You know the diameter of the circle and you know the center is the location where the major and minor axes intersect. Thus, just compute the radius `r` from the diameter, and for every pixel in your image, check to see if that pixel's Euclidean distance from the cirlce's center is less than `r`. If so, color the pixel white. Otherwise, leave it alone.

```
[M,N] = size(redChannel);
new_image = zeros(M,N);
for ii=1:M
    for jj=1:N
        if( sqrt((jj-center_x)^2 + (ii-center_y)^2) <= radius )
            new_image(ii,jj) = 1.0;
        end
    end
end
```

This can probably be optimzed by using the meshgrid function combined with logical indices to avoid the loops.

Comment: EMS, thanks again for some prompt feedback. With a bit of tweaking this worked well for the binarized image. But, I was wondering if there was a manner in which I could modify the code to also stretch the gray-scale version of the image? I want to be able to examine how the stretch affects the original image and filling it with white pixels would hamper that.

Comment: I see. So you're looking for the affine transformation that takes a given, known ellipse and maps it to a circle with diameter equal to the major axis. I don't know what the transformation matrix will look like for that off the top of my head, but it seems like it should be a well-known result listed in a standard text somewhere. Then you'll just use that transformation matrix to map your image's original coordinates to new ones. It might cut off stuff around the edge of the image, but should inflate the ellipse to a circle.

Comment: Yes, an affine transform was pretty much the same conclusion I arrived at - the challenge being formulating an appropriate transformation matrix. I'm going to continue tinkering.